# MassTransit Request/Response when Consumer is Down

Tags: masstransit

I'm using MassTransit 3.4 / RabbitMQ 3.6.5 and I love it, but have come across a problem.  I have 2 services, A and B.  When service A starts, it immediately calls service B via request/response pattern.  If B isn't running at the time, the message will timeout which is ok - service A is still set as running.  Later, when service B comes online, if service A makes the same request/response call, I'm expecting that it's going to work, but it's not.  The request is made, service B picks it up and does a RespondAsync with the proper message, but the response ends up in the service A's bus Skipped queue.  Why?  Is this scenario not supported?  How can I make sure that I can start up my services in any order and ensure that they'll work?

It's working fine if I start service B first, and then start service A, but I don't want to have to rely on this kind of hacky start sequence.

Each time I do the request/response, I'm getting the IRequestClient as it says in the docs like so...

```
IRequestClient<TRequest, TResponse> client = this.busControl.CreateRequestClient<TRequest, TResponse>(uri, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
return await client.Request(message);
```

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: Are you sure that this is the second response that ends up in the skipped queue? Because B should process both requests and for the first one it is too late anyway and no one is waiting for reply so it ends up in the deadletter queue but the second response should work fine.

Comment: Yes both the first and second response end up in the skipped queue.  It's not one of my named queues though, It's the skipped queue named like: bus-NODENAME-My.Service-somerandomcharacters_skipped.

Comment: Just to be sure, you're calling Start on the requestor IBusControl before making the request, correct?

Comment: @Andy If you put a repo on Github, I can look at it